# Equivalence of absolute values and topologies

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

> Let $| \ \  |_ 1$ and $| \ \ |_ 2$ be absolute values on $k$. Prove that the topologies on $k$ induced
>   by $| \ \ |_ 1$ and $| \ \ |_ 2$ coincide if and only if $| \ \ |_ 1$ and $| \ \ |_ 2$ are equivalent.

Here $k$ is a field and equivalent norm means sequences that are cauchy in one are cauchy in another and similarly convergent sequences in one are convergent in another. I know I am supposed to use Weak approximation lemma. (This is supposed to be a corollary of the weak approximation lemma)

I think $(\implies)$ is easy.
For the other way, I do not understand how weak approximation lemma should make its appearance.

Weak approximation lemma:

> Given inequivalent nontrivial absolute values $| \ |_ 1 , . . . , | \ |_ n$ on $k$, $a_ 1 , . . . , a_ n ∈ k$, and
>   $ \epsilon _1 , . . . , \epsilon_ n ∈ \mathbb R_{ >0}$ there exists $x ∈ k$ such that $|x − a_ i | _ i <  \epsilon _i$ for $i = 1, . . . , n.$

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly in this context is the "weak approximation lemma"?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, I do not see where one should use that lemma here. Rather, assuming that the topologies differ, i.e. there is some set $U$ open w.r.t. $\lvert \rvert_2$, and an $x\in U$ such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $B_\varepsilon(x)$ (w.r.t. $\lvert \rvert_1$) is not contained in $U$, it's straightforward to construct a sequence which converges to $x$ in the first, but not the second metric. (For a moment I though this might need the trivial case $n=1$ in the lemma, but I think it does not, as we actually have a slightly different and potentially stronger statement.)